# Changing location of sprite based on rotation of another sprite SDL2 & C++11

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, sdl

I have a space themed game with a spaceship that moves around with the camera and rotates using the SIN&COS functions, to a 1 degree accuracy. The spaceship moves and rotates correctly. I am now looking into firing shots from said spaceship.

So far I can create a shot going right from the spaceship no matter which direction it may be facing. However I was wondering if there is a way for me to spawn in a shot based on where the spaceship is facing? I can handle all angles of the shot after I have it spawned. I cannot yet figure out how to get it to spawn in front of the spaceship based on its rotation.

I am using SDL2 with C++ 11.

I do not want you to directly tell me the code if possible, because I will not learn anything from that. I am using this as a learning experience. Would I need to state points of the spawn location for each 1 degree angle of the spaceships 360 degree turning cycle? Or is their a more dynamic way of doing such a thing?

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate x and y offsets by applying trigonometric functions to ship rotation. Add that to ship position and you will get absolute position of projectile. For example:

```
bulletRotation = shipRotation;
bulletCenterX = shipCenterX + cos(shipRotation) * offset;
bulletCenterY = shipCenterY + sin(shipRotation) * offset;
```

If you already implemented the physics of bullets, you can also re-use that logic. Just make the bullet go forward a little bit.

Make sure not to mix degrees and radians.

Answer (score 0):

Let O be the center of your spaceship, Ox a reference axis with O as origin, and A the point you are looking for. The coordinates of A can easily be determined as long as you know its distance from O (which should be constant if your spaceship only rotates) and the angle theta between OA and Ox.

Relative to O,

```
Ax = OA * cos(theta)
Ay = OA * sin(theta)
```

To get the absolute coordinates, just add the relative ones to the coordinates of O.

I don't know how you calculate the trajectories of your shots, but you can do so in a similar way (you only need to change the distance OA, as long as O doesn't move).